# Images fade effect and infinite scrolling

Tags: fade, infinite-scroll

I know that this question has been already asked a few times: I tried those solutions but they didn't work for me.
I have a blog with infinite scrolling and a script for a fade effect on images.
The mouse over fade doesn't work with the images loaded with infinite scrolling. 
How can I fix this problem?
I would also like to add     `.stop()` function, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the fade effect code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
$('img').hover(function() {
$(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.8);
}, function() {
$(this).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
});
});
//]]> 
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Bro, how can you expect us to understand the problem without looking at the structure of your code or the URL?
But anyway, I think since you are using infinite scroll and probably loading the images through ajax or anything similar and you are attaching the event handlers at document ready.

Therefore, you might try using jQuery on() instead of hover() or live() if you are using an older version of jquery.